# Angular 4 Declaration file error

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to intergarate the textcomplete plugin for my angular 4 application. I have installed the package through npm but when i try to import the same it is throwing the following error.

Could not find a declaration file for module 'textcomplete'. 'c:/Users/name/Downloads/cli-quickstart/node_modules/textcomplete/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/textcomplete` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'textcomplete';
Please help.

I also need textcomplete jquery plugin in my application so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to install this npm install @types/textcomplete

Comment: Show how you have imported it ?

Comment: @Chellappan i have tried using the command npm install @types/textcomplete. but it is not working.

Comment: what is the issue now?

Comment: i have used different plugin for autocomplete textarea. below is the link https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-text-input-autocomplete/docs/. thanks for your comments :)